# Why FieldError is showing in Django?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a search form using django which will render result according to search value. All fields are working fine except one field.

HTML Code

```
<form action="{% url 'search' %}">
                <label">State</label>
                <select name="state">
                  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">State (All)</option>
                  {% for k,v in state_choices.items %}
                    <option value="{{k}}">{{v}}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <label>Bedrooms</label>
                <select name="bedrooms">
                  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Bedrooms (Any)</option>
                  {% for k,v in bedroom_choices.items %}
                    <option value="{{k}}">{{v}}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
                </select>
            <button type="submit">Submit form</button>
          </form>
```

Django code

```py
def search(request):
    result = Listing.objects.order_by('-list_date')

    # state
    if 'state' in request.GET:
        state = request.GET['state']
        if state:
            result = result.filter(state = state)

    # bedrooms
    if 'bedrooms' in request.GET:
        bedrooms = request.GET['bedrooms']
        if bedrooms:
            result = result.filter(bedrooms_lte = bedrooms)

    context = {
        'state_choices': state_choices,
        'bedroom_choices': bedroom_choices,
        'listings': result
    }
    return render(request, 'listings/search.html', context)
```

The `bedrooms` is creating the problem. Below is the error am getting :

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/listings/search?keywords=&city=&bedrooms=2&price=1000000

Django Version: 3.0.1
Python Version: 3.6.9
Installed Applications:
['pages.apps.PagesConfig',
 'listings.apps.ListingsConfig',
 'realtors.apps.RealtorsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/listings/views.py", line 44, in search
    result = result.filter(bedrooms_lte = bedrooms)
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 904, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 923, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1340, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1371, in _add_q
    check_filterable=check_filterable,
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1240, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1077, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/home/barefaced/Desktop/ubuntu/mini projects/django/practice/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1473, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /listings/search
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'bedrooms_lte' into field. Choices are: address, bathrooms, bedrooms, city, description, garage, id, is_published, list_date, lot_size, photo_1, photo_2, photo_3, photo_4, photo_5, photo_6, photo_main, price, realtor, realtor_id, sqft, state, title, zipcode
```

Please help me out to solve the problem. i am totally new in Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add another underscore between bedrooms and lte.

```
result.filter(bedrooms__lte=bedrooms)
```